# What Unix/Linux editor can I use that does not allow me to exit to a command prompt?

Tags: linux, unix, text-editors

I need to edit files owned by root without using the root uid.
Vi (via sudo) is not allowed because you can exit to a command prompt shell. IS there an editor that I can use (via sudo probably) that does not allow me to exit to a shell?

Thanks for any assistance..

Cheers!
Stephen

Comment: If you let someone edit a root-owned file, then s/he can likely get all required privileges through this. If you want to pursue this, better edit a copy of the file with any plain editor, and have a cron job move that copy to where it counts.

Comment: Do you mean "exit" like "terminate the editor and return to its parent shell"? or do you refer to the ability of `vi` to run `:sh` or `:!any_command`?

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there an editor that I can use (via sudo probably) that does not allow me to exit to a [root] shell?**

Any of them. You just have to configure and use sudo appropriately.

The [manual page for sudoedit](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudoedit) says

> When invoked as sudoedit, the -e option (described below), is implied.
>
> -e' The -e (edit) option indicates that, instead of running a command, the user wishes to edit one or more files. In lieu of a command, the string "sudoedit" is used when consulting the security policy. If the user is authorized by the policy, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Temporary copies are made of the files to be edited with the owner set to the invoking user.
> 2. The editor specified by the policy is run to edit the temporary files. The sudoers policy uses the SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables (in that order). If none of SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, the first program listed in the editor sudoers(5) option is used.
> 3. If they have been modified, the temporary files are copied back to their original location and the temporary versions are removed.

---

- [How do I edit a file as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104429/2974)

Answer (score 0):

When you edit file with **sudo** via the user ID that is *non-root* you exit to the user ID with which you have entered the **VI/VIM** editor. It is not a problem editing the files via **sudo** (files owned by root).